# How to retry http request on timeout?

Tags: haskell, httprequest

I often have got timeouts in my download method, I want to add some retries here:

```
withSocketsDo $ do
    irequest  ← liftIO $ parseUrl url
    fileExist ← doesFileExist fname
    when fileExist $ do
        putStrLn " -> Removing old version"
        removeFile fname
    withManager $ \manager → do
        let request = irequest
             { method = methodGet
             , responseTimeout = Just 10000000 }
        response ← http request manager
        responseBody response C.$$+- sinkFile fname
```

I've found method with `ScopedTypeVariables`

```
retryOnTimeout ∷ IO a → IO a
retryOnTimeout action = catch action $ \ (_ :: HttpException) → do
    putStrLn "Timed out. Trying again."
    threadDelay 5000000
    action
```

Adding try count is not big problem but seems like I can't just use something alike

```
response ← retryOnTimeout ( http request manager )
```

Because it cause strange type conflicts

```
Couldn't match type `IO'
              with `resourcet-1.1.3.3:Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT
                      IO'
Expected type: resourcet-1.1.3.3:Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT
                 IO
                 (Network.HTTP.Conduit.Response
                    (C.ResumableSource IO Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString))
  Actual type: IO
                 (Network.HTTP.Conduit.Response
                    (C.ResumableSource IO Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString))
```

How can I implement retry on Timeout for HTTP get method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that your code expects a `IO a`, but in fact is being given a `ResourceT IO a`. The easiest thing to do is:

- Change your type signature to match
- Use `catch` from `Control.Exception.Lifted` (in the `lifted-base` package) instead of from `Control.Exception`

Comment: should I use `resourcet` package for `ResourceT` ?

Comment: and run other methods with `liftIO $ putStrLn "Timed out. Trying again."`

Comment: Yes to both questions